# ParseException Missing TABLE

Tags: csv, hive

I created `mytable` table in mydb, and when I do show tables on that db I see `mytable`.

However, when I do:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/my/hdfs/path/myfile.csv' OVERWRITE INTO mydb.mytable;
```

I get

```
ParseException line 1:73 missing TABLE at 'mydb' near '<EOF>'
```

I can do a describe on the table, and I see my headers.

But how do I get the data from `myfile.csv` into the Hive table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query TABLE key is missing.So,instead of

LOAD DATA INPATH '/my/hdfs/path/myfile.csv' OVERWRITE INTO mydb.mytable;

use this---->

```
use mydb;
LOAD DATA INPATH '/my/hdfs/path/myfile.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE mytable;
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!